# find a differential equation with trig function and constant in angle

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the equation for this solution.
$y = x *\tan(x + c)$
When I take the derivative I get
$y' = \tan(x+c)+x*\sec(x+c)^2$
I do not see how I can get c out from the trig functions and determine its value,
to substitute in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y = x *\tan(x + c)$$
For $x \ne 0$
$$\arctan (\frac yx)=x+c$$
Implicit differentiation gives
$$\frac 1 {1+\frac {y^2}{x^2}}(\frac yx)' =1$$
$$y'x-y=x^2+y^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\tan^2(x)+1=\sec^2(x)$$